# Nonlinear Dynamics

Tags: differential, nonlinear-dynamics

Good afternoon,

I am working on Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos by Strogatz $2$nd Edition.

I am having trouble with problem $2.14$ on pg $36$.

The question is about the analytic solution of $\frac{dx}{dt} = \sin x$. We are given the $x(t)$ as follows:

```
 x(t) = 2arctan(e^t / 1+2^1/2 )
```

We are asked to derive this from

```
                      t = ln abs[ csc(x_0) + cot(x_0) / cscx + cotx ]
```

For  $x_0 = \frac{pi}{4}$

My problem is how to deal with this problem at $x_0$ = integer multiples of $\pi$

Also, how do I get rid of the absolute value sign when attempting to solve for $x$ in terms of $t$.

Lastly, how would you do the same problem for arbitrary initial value $x_0$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- You're missing a logarithm from your expression for $\ t\ $, which should be
  $$
  t=\ln\left|\frac{\csc x_0+\cot x_0}{\csc x + \cot x}\right|
  $$
- Your first equation
  $$
  x=2\arctan\left(\frac{e^t}{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)
  $$
  is the solution *for $\ x_0=\frac{\pi}{4}\ $*.  You're not asked to derive that from the expression for $\ t\ $ with *arbitrary* $\ x_0\ $, but merely to show that it is the solution when $\ x_0=\frac{\pi}{4}\ $.
- Since $\ e^t>0\ $, then if $\ x\ $ satisfies the equation
  $$
  e^t= \frac{\csc x_0+\cot x_0}{\csc x + \cot x}
  $$
  it will automatically satisfy the equation
  $$
  e^t=\left|\frac{\csc x_0+\cot x_0}{\csc x + \cot x}\right|\ .
  $$
  So, provided any solution you propose satisfies the first of these equations, you can effectively ignore the absolute value signs.
- Part (b) of the question does ask you to find an "analytic solution" for $\ x(t)\ $ given an arbitrary initial value $\ x_0\ $. If $\ x_0\ $ is an integer multiple of $\ \pi\ $, then $\ \sin x_0=0\ $, and the solution of the differential equation is $\ x(t)=0\ $, for all $\ t\ $.  After you've derived an analytic expression for $\ x(t)\ $ for $\ x_0\ $ *not* an integer multiple of $\ \pi\ $, you should be able to write it in a form such that when you substitute $\ x_0=2n\pi\ $ in that expression, where $\ n\ $ is an integer, it will give you $\ x(t)=0\ $ anyway, so the expression will in fact then be valid for those cases as well.

  However, since I think the expression must contain a term of the form
  $\ \tan\frac{x_0}{2}\ $ (or equivalent), which is undefined when $\ x_0\ $ is an *odd* multiple of $\ \pi\ $, the general formula will not be valid for those cases.

Comment: Thank you for drawing attention to the errors. I really enjoy the clever justification to ignore the absolute value sign, though I would be lying if i said I didn't feel uneasy about it still. What I had initially proposed is given any initial value not an integer multiple of pi, around a small open interval of it, the sign of the denominator and the number-tor is the same. So, we could perhaps ignore the absolute value sign altogether. Please enlighten me if this is proper or not.

Comment: I agree with your reason for concluding that the fraction must be non-negative in any small interval around $\ t=0\ $.  I wouldn't quite say that you can ignore the absolute value sign *altogether*, but as  it happens, for any non-zero solution of the differential equation, $\ \frac{\csc x_0+\cot x_0}{\csc x + \cot x} \ $ will always positive, so the absolute value signs are unnecessary, but before you can ignore them you need to recognise that fact.

Comment: I've just realised I missed a factor of $\ \frac{1}{2}\ $ in what I think is the expression for the solution. I've now corrected my answer in the light of that realisation.